Why do I get JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 4 (char 3)
from autots import AutoTS
model = AutoTS(forecast_length=10, frequency='infer',ensemble='simple', drop_data_older_than_periods=200)
model = model.fit(data, date_col='Date', value_col='Close', id_col=None)

It gives me this error when I try to run it.
Using 1 cpus for n_jobs.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-eb76a397227f> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 from autots import AutoTS
----> 2 model = AutoTS(forecast_length=10, frequency='infer',ensemble='simple', drop_data_older_than_periods=200)
      3 model = model.fit(data, date_col='Date', value_col='Close', id_col=None)

2 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):
--> 340             raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
    341         return obj
    342 

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 4 (char 3)

I have already installed these libraries. I was trying to use the autots library from Python but couldn't use it because it gives me this error and I am confused whats wrong in it.
!pip install auto_ts
!pip install autots


Clearly, it returns some malformed JSON. We can't see the response and you haven't provided enough data to allow us to reproduce the problem. Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

what other information do you need?

Which library exactly is this, which version, installed how? Does the problem reproduce on a different computer?

The library is  AutoTS from AutoML in Python and I used Google Collab to install it. The version is this auto_ts-0.0.92-py3

https://github.com/winedarksea/AutoTS/issues/243 -- its a bug in AutoTS, error in the template was introduced few weeks ago (or at least thats what the git blame says). Downgrade AutoTS or wait for fix

https://github.com/winedarksea/AutoTS/issues/243

You also have a confusion here, the auto_ts library is completely unrelated to the autots library I maintain. Please head to the GitHub Discussions section of winedarksea/AutoTS for the best help directly for this package.

This is bug in AutoTS.
https://github.com/winedarksea/AutoTS/blame/7a843d050f62c1b4046c0b08020838e8eb95388a/autots/templates/general.py#L467
As seen on that row, it has '"  at the start and that causes the json decoder to fail.
Downgrade autots for quick fix.
